# Error using basic webview - Android

Tags: android, android-webview

I am trying out a very simple `webview` application on Android. While the program builds OK, there are run-time errors that I cannot decode. The layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

   <Webview xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@+id/helloWebview"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     />
```

The code:

```
/* Program to create sample webview.
 * Steps:
 * 1. Create webview.
 * 2. Show some website in it.
 * 3. Show some transitions as well.
 */

package com.sriram.hellowebview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class helloWebview extends Activity {

    WebView myWebview;
    String url = "http://www.google.com";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hello_webview);

        Log.v(this.toString(), "Starting activity.");

        myWebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.helloWebview);

        Log.v(this.toString(), "Getting settings.");
        //myWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        Log.v(this.toString(), "Loading URL now.");
        myWebview.loadUrl(url);
        Log.v(this.toString(), "Loaded URL.");

        //open all links within the same webview.
        //myWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        //Log.v(this.toString(), "All done here.");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_hello_webview, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

The error observed:

```
03-24 14:48:27.618: E/AndroidRuntime(388): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
03-24 14:48:27.658: E/AndroidRuntime(388): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sriram.hellowebview/com.sriram.hellowebview.helloWebview}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class Webview
```

I have come across similar errors that detail OutOfMemoryExceptions in large projects, but since the above code is all there is to the project, this does not seem a likely explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is typo mistake in your layout: WebView need to be written in CamelCase. There isn't such view as 'Webview'. So your layout should look as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/helloWebview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You are receiving this error as you are not having any parent layout for webview.

Change your xml file as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

   <LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   />

   <WebView
       android:id="@+id/helloWebview"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     />
```

Hope it helps.